# Ruby use Sudo GUI instead of command line

Tags: ruby, sudo

I was wondering if it is possible to invoke a sudo GUI prompt instead of prompting through the terminal such as

```
osascript -e 'do shell script \" command here \" with administrator privileges'
```

and how I would go about it in ruby.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Is there a particular reason why you'd prefer an additional layer of abstraction?

Comment: Can you explain how I would do it? I think it's this line that needs to be changed:   
safe_system 'sudo', 'installer', '-pkg', pkg_file, '-target', target_device

Comment: Maybe this would help?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/164819/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-a-gui-as-admin-from-a-non-admin-user-session

Comment: Thanks but this seems to apply only to linux. I know mac has osascript to achieve a similar result but I'm not quite sure how to integrate this into the homebrew formula